# Python3 and xml/xslt libraries

Tags: python-3.x, libxml2, libxslt

In python 2.6 I did this to achieve an xsl tranform

```
    import libxml2
    import libxslt
    ...
    styledoc = libxml2.parseFile(my_xslt_file)
    style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(styledoc)
    doc = libxml2.parseDoc(siri_response_data)
    result = style.applyStylesheet(doc, None)
    ...
```

What would be the equivalent in Python 3.2?

I ask because it seems that lnxml and libxslt are not available in python3.2. I have heard of lxml - is this a direct equivalent of libxml2 + libxslt or does it have different calling patterns (needing rewriting of the code)?

Comment: I think libxml2/xslt libraries now offer Python3 bindings via the `./configure` script argument `--with-python=${PATH_TO_PYTHON3_BINARY}`, e.g., `/usr/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 4):

The analog of your code using [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt):

```
from lxml import etree

# ...    
styledoc = etree.parse(my_xslt_file)
transform = etree.XSLT(styledoc)
doc = etree.fromstring(siri_response_data)
result = transform(doc)
# ...
```

`lxml` lists support for Python 3.2

[`lxml` uses `libxml2/libxslt` under the hood](http://lxml.de/installation.html) so results should be the same. It uses Cython to generate C extensions that work both on Python 2.x and 3.x from the same source, [example](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/tree.pxd).