# Transform XML files with XSLT in python 3.4

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xslt, python-3.x, lxml

I'm on Windows 8.1 64bit, i have python 3.4 and I am trying to transform xml files to another format of xml and to transform **csv|tsv** files into xml. I've heard that **XSLT** is exactly what i should use for it.

I've read that there's a python module called **lxml** that supports **XSLT** but according to **[this](http://lxml.de/installation.html#requirements)** its only for **python 2.6 or later** and from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971173/python3-and-xml-xslt-libraries)** it can be compatible to **python 3.2** at max.

I tried installing the module to see if it'll work typing `pip install lxml` in the terminal but it gave me:

```
 copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DEVELO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_user-name\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" i
Install --record C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hb0evc4o-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user-name\lxml
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Development\pip\pip.log
```

I'm also wondering if I can just use python 3.4 for my main program and python 2.7 for the sole purpose of transforming my files. I would have to run it in a server and I'm not sure if it would mess everything up.

Comment: Check these [binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) for Windows

Comment: Hi, I've tried installing one and the module seems to importing ! .. would the library work properly now like it should ? sorry, i don't really understand what the difference between installing modules as binaries and installing thel directly by python (pip | easy install) .. sorry, i would really appreciate an explenation.. thank you :)